# Restore Illustrator panel zoom level

Tags: adobe-illustrator

No idea how I managed to do this, but the zoom level from my properties panel suddenly changed. Everything is now unusably tiny.

[image]

How do I restore this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Illustrator probably reverted your settings to default scaling. You can change that in Preferences menu (Ctrl + K) and in interface tab. There is a UI scale slider that you can adjust.

https://gyazo.com/80d81480069c76032d2d37b53312e46f

Note that when you change that setting you need to restart Illustrator in order to change make an effect.